# Is there a way to put a bolded, non-italicized "Figure" label above the title in APA 7th edition style in ggplot (in R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After reading the APA 7th edition style guide, I found out that I need a figure label (bold, unitalicized) above the title (not bold, italicized). ChatGPT can't seem to give me useable code in this case. Typically `theme_cowplot()` is used for APA-like formatting but I need it to be exactly to the standards, so I created my own theme:

```
{r}
theme_apa <- function(){
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = "italic", # Use "plain" for regular text
                              size = 12), # Adjust the size as needed
    legend.position = "right",
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),  # Bolds x title
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),  # Bolds y title
    strip.text = element_text(size = 12),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), # Set the background color to white
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black") # prevents axes from disappearing
)}
```

And applied it to my linear regression plot:

```
{r}
# linear regression plot
ggplot(autism_data, aes(x = Autism_Scale, y = Coord)) +
  geom_point(color = "gray", size = .5) + # adds scatterplot w/ low opacity points
  geom_smooth(color="black", method = "lm") + # adds line w/ 95% CI
  xlab("Autism Measure Score") + ylab("Coordination Level") + # axis labels
  labs(title = "Figure 1:\nSynchrony as a Function of Autism Measure Score") + #title
 theme_apa() + # applies APA formatting (mostly)
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                                 after_stat(rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*"))) # equation
```

This gets me 98% of the way there, but the only snag is that figure formatting. Right now, using this exact code, the "Figure 1" is exactly where it needs to be and the title is perfect. It just needs bolded and unitalicized. Is there any way to do this simply?

I tried `theme_cowplot()`, but that didn't suffice. So I made my own theme for APA formatting, which got me most of the way there, but I can't figure out how to format that "Figure" portion. ChatGPT tried to use `expression()` within `labs(title = )` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The package `ggtext` lets you format your plot labels with `element_markdown`.

In your `theme_apa` I changed the title to `plot.title = element_markdown(size = 12)`.

```
library(ggtext)

theme_apa <- function(){
        theme(
                plot.title = element_markdown(size = 12), # Adjust the size as needed
                legend.position = "right",
                axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
                axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
                axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),  # Bolds x title
                axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),  # Bolds y title
                strip.text = element_text(size = 12),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), # Set the background color to white
                axis.line = element_line(color = "black") # prevents axes from disappearing
        )}
```

While creating your plot you can now use markdown operators to format specific snippets:

```
labs(title = "**Figure 1**:\\\n*Synchrony as a Function of Autism Measure Score*")
```

Note that I had to double escape `\n` to get a new line.

#### Example Output:

[image]